# How to disable subtitles?

Tags: mplayer

When I play videos in mplayer it sometimes shows subtitles.  How can I turn them off?

And can I change `mplayer.conf` so they are off by default?

Comment: Depends on the video, some videos have subtitles hard-coded in (i.e. overlayed on the picture, won't remove).  Others have a separate subtitle track (external file)... Others still may have a track encoded in it that have them.  But `v` is the keyboard toggle during playback.  Types 2/3 this should work for - type 1 you are "SOL".

Comment: Thanks `v` worked to turn them off.

Comment: Glad to help, moved it to an answer (as it should have been originally).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try hitting the <kbd>v</kbd> on your keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

There are also CLI options `-nosub` (for disabling subtitles that come within an .mkv, for example) and `-noautosub` (for disabling external subtitles from a separate file).

So, to run a video without any subtitles, you can do the following:

```
mplayer -noautosub -nosub filename.mkv
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the video:

1. Some videos have subtitles hard-coded in (i.e. overlayed on the picture, won't remove).
2. Others have a separate subtitle track (external file)...
3. Others still may have a track encoded in it that have them.

But <kbd>v</kbd> is the keyboard toggle during playback. Types 2/3 this should work for - type 1 you are "SOL".

Comment: To complete your original ask… add the following line to your ~/.mplayer/config file… nosub = true. This will prevent the subtitles from being loaded at all, so you won’t have to type ‘v’.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Devid](https://superuser.com/users/172416/devid) said, <kbd>v</kbd> is the shortcut for it. But you could also change the `mpv.conf` file:

```
sub-visibility=no # Disable display of subtitles, but still load them if available.
```

Sources:

- [Example of `mpv.conf` from Phate66660](https://codeberg.org/Phate6660/mpv-config/src/commit/1b979bc7386b6d56f5eb4d0cf3b1c2a7976c4324/mpv.conf#L12)
- [MPV Subtitle Official Docs](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#subtitles=)

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.